# list index out of range example PyomoBook

Tags: python, pandas, pyomo

I'm starting to work with Pyomo and Python, I am following the examples in the book Pyomo Optimization Modeling in Python.
I am trying to solve the Warehouse problem. And I am trying to import the parameters from an Excel file, as indicated in the book:

```
import pandas

import sys

from pyomo.environ import*


df = pandas.read_excel(sys.argv[1], 'Delivery Costs',header=0, index_col=0)

model = ConcreteModel(name = "WL")

N = list(df.index.map(str))
M = list(df.columns.map(str))
d = {(r, c):df.at[r,c]for r in N for c in M}
P = int(sys.argv[2])


model.x = Var(N, M, bounds=(0,1))
model.y = Var(N, within=Binary)

def obj_rule(model):
    return sum(d[n,m]*model.x[n,m] for n in N for m in M)
model.obj = Objective(rule=obj_rule)


def one_per_cust_rule(model, m): # Es necesario poner m porque queremos que lo  haga para cada cliente
    return sum(model.x[n,m]for n in N) == 1

model.one_per_cust = Constraint(M, rule=one_per_cust_rule)


def warehouse_active_rule(model, n, m):
    return model.x[n,m] <= model.y[n]

model.warehouse_active = Constraint(N, M, rule=warehouse_active_rule)
   
def num_warehouses_rule(model):
    return sum(model.y[n] for n in N) <= P

model.num_warehouses = Constraint(rule=num_warehouses_rule)


opt = SolverFactory('glpk')
results = opt.solve(model)
model.pprint()
```

But when I run the code, I get the following error:

IndexError: list index out of range

What is going wrong?

Comment: How do you execute your script? With your code you have to pass an argument like `python myscript.py data.xlsx`

Comment: This line looks wrong 'from pyomo. environ import*'  is it exactly what you have?  are the spaces in the correct spots? I am not familiar with pyomo but I would have expected 'from pyomo.environ import *' and also in general it is bad practice to import * in Python.  It is best to specifically import the things you want from that module.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I'm running the script from Spyder IDE.

I have tried running the script line by line to detect where the error occurs. The error appears at ' df = pandas.read_excel(sys.argv[1], 'Delivery Costs',header=0,.index_col=0)'.

Delivery Costs.xlsx is in the same directory where my WareHouse_Excel_Concrete.py script is.

As for the line 'from pyomo. environ import*' in my code I have it well written. I'm sorry I posted it wrong.

Regarding if it is good to use 'import*' or not, I can only say that I am learning with the Pyomo book, and in the examples they always do it that way.

Comment: Just replace `sys.argv[1]` by `"Delivery Costs.xlsx"` and it will work.